# django redirects not working in electronjs

Tags: django, electron

I am creating an account management app for my father's company. I integrated Django with electron like this:

```
mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:8000')
```

And in `package.json`:

```
"start": "start python manage.py runserver && start electron ."
```

In my **createView, DetailView, DeleteView**. I added this:

```
success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

If i open this in chrome browser it works absolutely fine no worries.
But if i do this in electron. It show this msg

[Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/delete/11
Raised by:  accounts.views.EntryDeleteView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErHO7.png)

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Can you share the code to your views.py?

Comment: @ShahulHameed, please help

Answer (score 0):

Here you go @Shahul Hameed

~~ALL imports~~

```
class EntryListView(ListView):
    model = Entries
    template_name = 'accounts/home.html'

class EntryDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Entries

class EntryCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Entries
    fields = [~~All fields~~]
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

class EntryUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Entries
    fields = [~~All fields~~]
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

class EntryDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Entries
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```